# Magento upgrade script doesn't upgrade

Tags: php, mysql, magento, attributes

I've been trying to make a upgrade script for a custom attribute. However, the upgrade script doesn't seem to work. It doesn't update the site nor the mysql database.

All it needs to do, is switch group from "General" to "Prijzen".

Every time I try to upgrade the module the version number doesn't change and nor does the group. Can't seem to find the wrong turn I'm taking.

MySQL DB `core_resources`:

```
topperquotation_setup  |  0.1.0  |  0.1.0
```

modules `config.xml`:

```
<config>
    <modules>

        <Topper_Quotation>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </Topper_Quotation>

    </modules>

    <global>

        <resources>
            <topperquotation_setup>
                <setup>
                    <module>Topper_Quotation</module>
                    <class>Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Setup</class>
                </setup>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_setup</use>
                </connection>
            </topperquotation_setup>
        </resources>

        <template>
            <email>
                <topp...........
```

original `install-0.1.0.php`:

```
<?php
/** @var Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Setup $installer */
$installer = $this;
$installer->startSetup();

$installer->addAttribute('catalog_product', 'is_quotable', array(
    'group'             => 'General',
    'type'              => 'int',
    'backend'           => '',
    'frontend'          => '',
    'label'             => 'Offerteaanvraag',
    'input'             => 'select',
    'class'             => '',
    'source'            => 'eav/entity_attribute_source_boolean',
    'global'            => Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Attribute::SCOPE_GLOBAL,
    'visible'           => true,
    'required'          => false,
    'user_defined'      => false,
    'default'           => '0',
    'searchable'        => false,
    'filterable'        => false,
    'comparable'        => false,
    'visible_on_front'  => false,
    'unique'            => false,
    'apply_to'          => 'simple,virtual,bundle',
    'is_configurable'   => false,
));

$installer->endSetup();
```

current `upgrade-0.1.0-1.0.0.php`:

```
<?php
/** @var Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Setup $installer */
$installer = $this;
$installer->startSetup();

$installer->updateAttribute('catalog_product', 'is_quotable', 'group', 'Prijzen');

$installer->endSetup();
```

Comment: Simple things first - have you turned caching off, and cleared `var/cache`?

Comment: Oh I feel so dumb haha! I clean cache so many times and just when I don't think of cache this happens. Thanks for the reminder ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Created comment as answer so this can be closed*

Make sure you've turned caching off and cleared `var/cache`. Magento keeps a copy of all configuration `.xml` files in the cache (which is actually all config files merged together) - so this needs to be cleared before it recognises the version number has changed.